# Sed to edit header with the contents of another file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to replace an existing header in a file based on the contents of another file.

File1 - names.in:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

File2- Datafile.tsv:

```
chr  begin  end  genes  genes genes genes  genes
```

`File2` contains more lines but I want to replace each occurrence of the string `genes` in the first line with the successive entries from `file1`, so that the header becomes:

```
chr  begin  end  name1.Corrected  name2.Corrected  name3.Corrected  name4.Corrected name5.Corrected
```

I tried the following script:

```
genenames=$1 
sed -i -e "1s/\tgenes/\t$genenames\.Corrected/g" Datafile.tsv
```

But when I run it like so:

```
./sed.sh names.in
```

I get the output as:

```
chr  begin  end  .in.Corrected  .in.Corrected  .in.Corrected  .in.Corrected  .in.Corrected
```

I can understand that the script does not read from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
for x in $(<names.in)
do
sed -i -s "s/ genes/ ${x}.Corrected/" Datafile.tsv
done

cat Datafile.tsv

chr  begin  end  name1.Corrected  name2.Corrected name3.Corrected name4.Corrected  name5.Corrected
```

- do not use `/g` flag which will apply to all occurences (you want to replace one by one)
- replace my `' '` by `'\t'`
- `$names.in` would expand to "the value of names variable" (concatenate to .in), this would likely expand to .in
- `$(< name.in )` read file name.in, before command execution and replace with content of file ( end-of-line turn to white)

a more comprehensive shell

```
cat "$1" | while read x
do
sed -i -s "s/ genes/ ${x}.Corrected/" "$2"
done
```

called as

```
 myscript.sh names.in  Datafile.tsv
```

Comment: If this is a huge file you're going to open/edit the file `N` times just to replace `N` occurrences of `genes`. Also, it will substitute on every line that matches not only on the first line.

Comment: Hi Archemar, may I ask why you have passed input as $(<name.in) instead of "$1"or simply use "$names.in"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your correctly, you need to read the names from `file1` and replace each occurrence of the string `genes` with successive entries from file1 but only in the first line of file2. If so, you could do this (assuming that you never have a string with `genes` as a substring, e.g. `mygenes`):

```
while read name
do
    sed -i "1s/genes/$name.Corrected/" file2
done < file1
```

Alternatively, you could also simply concatenate the contents of file1 and replace everything in one go:

```
names=$(perl -pe 's/\n/.Corrected /' file1)
sed -i "1s/genes .*/$names/" file2
```

Answer (score 2):

[Nothing beats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) a `while read` loop when processing text but just in case you wanted to process your `datafile.tsv` *only once*:

```
sed 's|\(.*\)|1s/genes/\1.Corrected/|' names.in | sed -f - datafile.tsv
```

The first `sed` turns `names.in` into a *sed script*:

```
1s/genes/name1.Corrected/
1s/genes/name2.Corrected/
1s/genes/name3.Corrected/
1s/genes/name4.Corrected/
1s/genes/name5.Corrected/
```

which is then executed by the second `sed`.
If all your *genes* columns are consecutive (like in your sample input) you could also run:

```
tr \\n \\t <names.in | \
sed -E 's|\t|.Corrected&|g;s|(.*).$|1s/genes.*genes/\1/|' | \
sed -f - datafile.tsv
```

which is similar to the first one, as the last `sed` executes the following *sed script*:

```
1s/genes.*genes/name1.Corrected name2.Corrected name3.Corrected name4.Corrected name5.Corrected/
```

---

Note that these won't edit your file in-place. To do that either use `sed` with `-i` (if supported) or redirect `>` the output to e.g. `newfile` then `mv newfile datafile.tsv`